# Prevent autoincrement of id after IGNORE INTO statement in sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite

I found a few duplicate threads talking about using option `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0` but I don't know how to do that in SQLite.

Here is my code:

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users(name, lastname) VALUES(?, ?)");
ps.setString(1, nameField.getText());
ps.setString(2, lastNField.getText());
int res = ps.executeUpdate();
```

`name` and `lastname` are set as unique keys. This works as expected (doesn't insert if name and last name already exist) but autoincrements my `id` every time. Any idea how to approach this by either fixing the autoincrement or changing the sql code? I'm doing this in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the AUTOINCREMENT from the table definition.

A plain INTEGER PRIMARAY KEY column [still is autoincrementing](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), but does not keep a separate counter. Instead, new rows just get the next ID after the largest one currently in the table.

AUTOINCREMENT is useful only if you want to prevent the IDs from deleted rows from being reused.